# android add device in Eclipse graphical layout

Tags: android, eclipse, user-interface

Like i can create custom `AVD's` i would like to create custom device preview to my graphical layout. Is it possible to do and how ?

Otherwise there are no other options(that i know) to preview custom devices without making AVD and viewing it in emulator, and that is very long process.

Comment: oh right there is a button `create new...` but i dont know what is that doing because selecting it nothing is happening...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are on the current version of the SDK tools and ADT plugin for Eclipse, any custom device definitions that you create in the AVD Manager should show up in the preview toolbar drop-down list of device definitions.

Comment: You will have to close and re-open Eclipse to see new ones.

Comment: Same for Android Studio. Needs to be restarted so devices appear in the list