# How to create Avd for Galaxy Nexus Note 2?

Tags: android

I want to develop my application for Galaxy Nexus Note 2 (5.5",Android OS 4.0 (Sandwitch)).

But I didnt understand how to Test this in my Eclipse.

There is no Galaxy Note option in my Device Definations.

How can I create this to test my application,like (Avd creation and 
(Graphical layout device options))

Thanks

Comment: There is no such device as "Galaxy Nexus Note 2" there's a "Samsung Galaxy Note 2" though

Comment: Only Nexus devices have AVD options and Samsung's Note is not one.

Answer (score 0):

You can always create custom AVDs according to your requirements.

- Click **Create New Device** in **Device Definitions Tab** in `AVD
  Manager`.
- Give the details of `AVD` to be Created.

P.S: There is no device named Galaxy Nexus Note 2. Either Nexus or Samsung Galaxy Note 2

Comment: How can Add this to my Graphical layout view for checking my xml,will it add automatically

Comment: I never checked it. But check this [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14946408/android-add-device-in-eclipse-graphical-layout/14946426#) given by *commonsware*.

Answer (score 0):

If the devices is not listed I would suggest that you clone the most similair device and the manually update the specs for your newly created device.

/Thomas