# Does Eclipse offer screen preview for Nexus 5?

Tags: android, eclipse-adt, nexus-4, graphical-layout-editor

I have my Android SDK up to date(22.3). It includes API 19. But I wander if does it support screen preview for Nexus 5 in the Layout XML Editor. The most performant  phone I can choose is Nexus 4. Is it missing or I have to do something special to be able to see it? If yes, what should I do?

[image]

**UPDATE:**

The `22.6` version of the Android SDK Tools offers preview for `Nexus 5` and `Nexus 7 II (1200x1920: xhdpi)`

Comment: possible duplicate of [Why there is no "Nexus 5" in AVD Manager? What option to use instead?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20360183/why-there-is-no-nexus-5-in-avd-manager-what-option-to-use-instead)

Comment: @CommonsWare yes... it could be considered duplicate. Basically this is what I want to know. My PC is not enough performant to create a Nexus 5 Emulator, so a preview would be very helpful.

Comment: The previews are drawn from the "Device Definitions" used to create AVDs. You do not need to create an AVD; you do need to create a device definition. Some future update of the tools will probably include a Nexus 5 definition; until then, define your own.

Comment: @CommonsWare Ok, Solved. The "Device Definition" does the job I need. The answer provided in the duplicate question is very good and should be accepted. I really didn't find it before. This 2 answer solve the problem: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20360183/why-there-is-no-nexus-5-in-avd-manager-what-option-to-use-instead and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14946408/android-add-device-in-eclipse-graphical-layout.

Answer (score 1):

You will either have to create the device yourself by putting in all of the dimensions or you can download an add-on such as GenyMotion which is around 10x faster to use as your emulator.

Genymotion: http://www.genymotion.com/

Comment: Genymotion has nothing to do with Eclipse's drag-and-drop GUI building and preview facility.

Comment: My apologies I must have misunderstood your initial question, I thought you were looking for the emulator itself.

Ignore that part of the answer, you will need to create the device definition on your own unfortunately.

Answer (score 1):

In addition to creating your own devices, I found the extra device definitions provided by Sony to be useful.  Go here for instructions: Install – [detailed instructions](http://developer.sonymobile.com/knowledge-base/sony-add-on-sdk/install-the-sony-add-on-sdk/install-detailed-instructions/)

EDIT:

Check out this too: [List Of Devices](http://checkscreensize.appspot.com/listdevice.jsp)

You can see that Sony's devices are the same as others in that list you may want to emulate.

In the emulator all you care about is screen size, dpi, and API.  You don't care what actual camera it has, what processor it's using, how big the HD is, and you can't use more than 768M of memory anyway.  The Sony Xperia Z1 == S5.

Comment: Yes, this seems very useful for Sony devices.

Comment: Not just "Sony".  Many of their devices are identical to others that are missing from the device definitions.